# Как получить такой эффект

Tags: css

Подскажите, как получить такой эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. 3 блок как бы размыт что ли..не знаю даже как описать словом )

Буду рад любому примеру. Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient

Comment: @entithat Благодарю